# Why did user "Community" endorse my duplicate closevote?

Tags: support

I just cast a closevote on [Usage of 'Jealous'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53525/usage-of-jealous). A few minutes later I noticed user ["Community"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) had resoundingly endorsed my vote and actually closed the question (no other votes were cast).

Since Community claims to be a "background process" rather than a real person, I don't really understand how it does this. I know that [on ELU I can unilaterally close questions with those specific tags for which I have a gold badge](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4807/a-single-vote-closes-a-question-have-i-just-been-granted-superpowers), but that doesn't seem to be the mechanism here. My "unilateral" closevotes on ELU show [a diamond after my username on the closevote notification](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/175522/term-for-a-yes-no-maybe-decision), and no endorsement from Community (which only stepped in a week later, to *delete* the question I'd closed as a dup in that link).

By what logic does Community decide whether my dup closevote should be immediately forced through without waiting for support from either a mod, or four other users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MARamezani's answer is correct. But you don't need a moderator or anyone else to confirm this - you can verify it yourself by hovering your mouse cursor over Community's user name on your question:

[image: This question's author approved a pending duplicate vote]

The little pop-up text tells the whole story.

Comment: I'm constantly impressed by the numerous ways in which the SE site programmers "go the extra mile". I should have had more faith, and studied the page itself to find an answer, rather than raising it here. (But since it *has* been raised here, I'll just say I hope those guys get reasonable wages for their sterling performance! :)

Answer (score 4):

With regards to the recent meta post on [a user's ability to admit their question is a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes)

> As of the 9th of March, the banner shown to askers whose questions have attracted at least one duplicate close vote has a couple of new options:
>   [image]
>   If the author clicks the first button, they're shown a confirmation that clarifies the results of this action somewhat:
>
> [image]
>   If they click "Ok", the question is instantly closed:
>   [image]

Which is what I think happened to that question.

Comment: Ah. So effectively, Community is endorsing ***the OP's decision*** to accept my closevote, rather than directly endorsing ***me***. That sounds like a rational/justifiable "bot-logic" approach to me, but I'll wait for confirmation from someone who definitely *knows* how it works before "ACCEPTING".